# Cucumber - Database cleaner is not working when default driver(selenium) is enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I am using cucumber + capybara for my tests.The database cleaner is working good, but when I change the Capybara.default_driver to selenium, database cleaner is not working. Below is my env.rb file.

```
Capybara.default_selector = :css
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = true

if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  begin
    require 'database_cleaner'
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  rescue LoadError => ignore_if_database_cleaner_not_present
  end
end

OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the database_cleaner [documentation](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner), hope it helps:

> One of my motivations for writing this library was to have an easy way
>   to turn on what Rails calls “transactional_fixtures” in my non-rails
>   ActiveRecord projects. For example, Cucumber ships with a Rails world
>   that will wrap each scenario in a transaction. This is great, but what
>   if you are using ActiveRecord in a non-rails project? You used to have
>   to copy-and-paste the needed code, but with DatabaseCleaner you can
>   now say:
>
> **#env.rb**

```
   require 'database_cleaner'
   require 'database_cleaner/cucumber'
   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
```

> Now lets say you are running your features and it requires that
>   another process be involved (i.e. Selenium running against your app’s
>   server.) You can simply change your strategy type:
>
> **#env.rb**

```
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'database_cleaner/cucumber'
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
```

> You can have the best of both worlds and use the best one for the job:
>
> **#env.rb**

```
require 'database_cleaner' 
require 'database_cleaner/cucumber'

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = (ENV['SELENIUM'] == 'true') ? :truncation : :transaction
```

Comment: great, negative vote and no comment. Next time go find an answer in google, if you like